# copy files and directory in java

Tags: java, file-copying

In my program I suppose to copy a directory to another directory with java. I did it but the only problem is that for the directories that are inside the source directory get copied but not the file inside them. Why?

This is the assigment:
Ask the user for the source directory and a destination.  The source is the directory to be copied; the destination is the directory that will be the parent of the new copy.

First your program should make a new directory in the new location with the same name as the source directory.  (You may need to do something special for root directories if you are copying an entire disk.  A root directory has no parent directory, and often, no name.)

Then your program should create an array with File class objects for each item in the contents of the source directory, similar to what was done in DirectoryListDemo.

Next , it should iterate the array, and  for each item in the array,
if it is a file, copy the file to the new directory using the copyFile() method taken from CopyFileDemoE.
if it is a directory, recursively call this method to copy the directory and all of its contents.

Here is the code:

```
package com.company;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner src = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter name of source directory to copy from: ");
        String sourceFile= src.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter name of destination directory to copy the files into: ");
        String destinationFile = (src.nextLine()+"/"+sourceFile);

        isDirFile(sourceFile, destinationFile);

    }
    public static void isDirFile(String source, String dest) throws Exception{

        File sourceFile = new File ("C:/"+source);
        File dirFile = new File (dest, new File(source).getName());
        dirFile.mkdirs();

        File[] entries;

        if (dirFile.exists()){
            if (sourceFile.isDirectory()){
                entries = sourceFile.listFiles();
                assert entries != null;
                for (File entry:entries){
                    if(entry.isFile()){
                        copyFile(entry.getAbsolutePath(),dest);
                    }
                    else{
                        isDirFile(entry.getAbsolutePath(),dest);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("File does not exist");
        }
    }
    public static void copyFile(String source, String destination) throws Exception{
        File sourceFile;
        File destFile;

        FileInputStream sourceStream;
        FileOutputStream destSteam;

        BufferedInputStream bufferedSource = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bufferedDestination = null;
        try{

            sourceFile = new File(source);
            destFile = new File (destination, new File(source).getName());

            sourceStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            destSteam = new FileOutputStream(destFile);

            bufferedSource = new BufferedInputStream(sourceStream, 8182);
            bufferedDestination = new BufferedOutputStream(destSteam, 8182);

            int transfer;

            System.out.println("Beginning file copy: ");
            System.out.println("\tcopying "+ source);
            System.out.println("\tto      "+destination);

            while ((transfer = bufferedSource.read()) != -1){
                bufferedDestination.write(transfer);
            }

        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(" An unexpected I/O error occurred.");
        }
        finally {
            if(bufferedSource != null){
                bufferedSource.close();
            }
            if(bufferedDestination != null){
                bufferedDestination.close();
            }
            System.out.println("Files closed. Copy complete.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When `isDirFile()` is called from itself, `sourceFile` will be set to `"C:\C:\…"`.

Comment: In the target, the directory tree will be 'flattened', meaning the contents from `source/x/y/z` is copied to `target/source/x`, `target/source/y`and `target/source/z`.

Comment: Thank you! What can I do to change it?

Comment: Seriously? Re-write the whole thing! Make a walk-through through your code and note the value of each variable after each line – this  should show you, what happens where. Next print the value of each variable after each line of your code to see where it deviates from your expectation. Finally fix it …